# MATLAB number formatting

Tags: matlab, formatting, numbers

I want to display numbers with excatly 5 decimal places, for
example

A = [3.1234,4.5678;5.6789,6.7891]

iwant to have the 5 decimal places of the answer.

A = [3.12345,4.56789;5.67891,6.78912]

Answer (score 0):

matlab show 4 decimal By default , you can change this with:

```
digits(5);
```

ex:

```
 A=1/3

vpa(A)

digits(5);
```

output : 0.33333

Answer (score 0):

[`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) can be used to output a matrix exactly as you specified:

```
A= rand(2);
disp(mat2str(A,5));
```